# open thumbnails in larger div

Tags: javascript, css, html, photo-gallery

hej there, I've got a question about functions of javascript and css.

I am trying to creat a css photo gallery, but I found out that a good gallery with thumbnails etc. is almost not possible in css only. So I want, when I click on the thumbnail, the picture opens bigger in another div.

I hope it's clear enough like this.

I am sorry for the bad english.

Comment: You have provided the background. What is your question?

Comment: Basically, what you want is a lightbox. Like shadowbox (http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) or lightbox 2 (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: CSS only lightboxes are very doable. See this link for an example of how": http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<a.some>
   <img.thumb>
   <span.popup>
      <img.big>
   </span>
</a>
```

css

```
a.some{position:relative}
a.some .popup{display: none;}
a.some:focus .popup{
   display:block;
}
```

something like this.

Comment: thank you for you time, but I can't get it to work. It just doesnt do anything. is the :focus something like in javascript onClick? and has the class .popup to be between the <a> tags? maby it is easier with javascript?